# How to call the next GET request by ID from POST request which creats a ID using "setNextRequest"

Tags: postman

Here is the scenario:

**Given** I have multiple input data(set in Pre-request script) for the POST request
**When** ID is returned 
**Then** Assert the details passing the ID with the GET request using the "setNextRequest" command from the POST request->Tests

**NOTE:** The tests are run from collection runner.

**Actual Behavior:**
It is not able to access the GET URL with the ID.

**Expected Behavior:**
I need to assert the details automatically from the collection runner.

````
Request Body:
{
    "name": "{{client_name}}",
    "email": "{{client_email}}"
}

Pre-request_script:
pm.environment.set("client_name","Client_" + new Date().getTime());
pm.environment.set("client_email", "Client_" + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9) + "@abc.com");

Tests:
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
if(jsonData.id){
    pm.environment.set("client-admin-client-id", jsonData.id);
    pm.sendRequest("GetClient By ID", function (err, response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(response.json()));
}); 
}else{
    postman.setNextRequest(null);
}```
````

Comment: What have you tried so far? What isn't working? Show us the pre-request code? This will only work in the Collection Runner if you're using `setNextRequest`.

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: You don't have any Tests with `pm.expect` statements, what are you asserting against? What is the `if` statement condition checking, just to see if the `id` property is there or not? You have a `pm.sendRequest()` in the `if` block - What's that doing? That's not the same as `setNextRequest()`.